# Pin window to desktop / Glue window to desktop / "Always-on-bottom" window

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, desktop-application

I'm working on a basic desktop app in C++ / Win32.

My goal right now is to create a basic "sticky note" app that would be **pinned / glued to the desktop**, i.e always in front of the desktop but always behind of any other application.
Really a personal project there, just to fight my bad memory and have my tasks/notes always visible on the desktop so I couldn't miss them when starting the computer & so on.

The behaviour I'm aiming for would be similar to **Stardock Fences** *("kind of" because I'm not going to store any desktop icon in there, but you hopefully get the idea)*

I started with the [sample code](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/windows/win32/learnwin32/your-first-windows-program) from the [Get Started with Win32 and C++ docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/windows/win32/learnwin32/) to have the most basic Win32 minimal window setup.

**What I got so far :**

1. I managed to keep my window on bottom of every other app and in front of the desktop by calling `SetWindowPos` in the window procedure (`WindowProc`), when handling the event `WM_SETFOCUS` *(I first tried with the event `WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING` as [suggested in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/528155/12742595) but this resulted in an annoying flickering when dragging the window)*.

```cpp
case WM_SETFOCUS:
        SetWindowPos(hwnd, HWND_BOTTOM, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOMOVE);
        return 0;
```

2. **The problem** : my window **stays in front of the desktop**, **except when I click** on the **"Show Desktop"** button in the taskbar (or hit the `Windows + D` shortcut). As I often use this shortcut myself, I'd like my window to stay over the desktop no matter what.
3. A not-satisfying-enough-but-still-something I managed to do is to bring back my window in front of the desktop when clicking on any other window after hitting Windows + D *(this mostly makes sense with multiple monitors, as opening a random app on the first one for example, will toggle back my own app in front of the desktop on another screen)*.
   I could do this using this time the event `WM_SIZE` and calling `ShowWindow` then `SetWindowPos`, still in the `WindowProc`

```cpp
case WM_SIZE:
        ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
        SetWindowPos(hwnd, HWND_BOTTOM, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOMOVE);
        return 0;
```

Not ideal though, as I'd really want my app to always remain in front of the desktop and "survive" to the Show Desktop action.

**What I tried :**

I checked out those answers but couldn't figure out how to achieve what I want.

1. [How to make 'always-on-bottom'-window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/527950/how-to-make-always-on-bottom-window)
2. [Window “on desktop”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/365094/window-on-desktop) : Note on this one, I tried the trick with `SetParent` like this in the `wWinMain`

```cpp
HWND desktop = FindWindow(L"ProgMan", L"Program Manager");
if (desktop == NULL)
{
    return 0;
}

ShowWindow(hwnd, nCmdShow);
SetParent(hwnd, desktop);
```

However, my app isn't visible at all anymore with this, even though the `FindWindow` didn't return `NULL` but an actual handle.

3. [Make aplication always on Bottom (pinned to desktop, behind all other apps) in C++/WinAPI [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20945609/make-aplication-always-on-bottom-pinned-to-desktop-behind-all-other-apps-in-c)
4. [Disable Minimize, Maximize, Close buttons in Win32](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36113675/disable-minimize-maximize-close-buttons-in-win32) I tried those to "intercept" the Show Desktop event but it seems this event doesn't get fired with the Show Desktop action.

Did I miss something ?

Comment: Are you handling the `WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING` message?

Comment: `WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING` is probably what you want to use. Set the `SWP_NOZORDER` flag to stop your z-order being changed. Show Desktop seems to be implemented by moving windows off-screen to -32000,-32000 so you should be able to check for that and set `SWP_NOMOVE` to prevent it.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, I tried handling the `WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING` with the following code :
```cpp
case WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING:
 SetWindowPos(hwnd, HWND_BOTTOM, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOZORDER);
 return 0;
```
(Seems I can't get formatting right in this comment, apologies )
However the behaviour is still the same ; when hitting `Windows + D` or clicking the desktop button, the window gets hidden :/
Did I miss something ?

Comment: No, you don't call `SetWindowPos` in response to that message. You modify the parameters of the `WINDOWPOS` structure that it passes you. See the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-windowposchanging).

Comment: @ZhuSong-MSFT Unfortunately desktop gadgets were dropped in Windows 8.

Comment: As far as I know, the window cannot remain visible when you select Show Desktop. You can refer to [How do I make a window remain visible even when the user selects Show Desktop?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20110617-00/?p=10403).

Comment: @ZhuSong-MSFT Yeah a gadget would be exactly what I want, but as Jonathan said, [they got completely removed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/w8cookbook/desktop-gadgets-removed)

Comment: @JonathanPotter thanks, I tried both setting `hwndInsertAfter` to `HWND_BOTTOM` and setting the `NO_ZORDER` flag (as it's said for the latter in the doc `Retains the current Z order (ignores the hwndInsertAfter member).`) So for the first method : ```cpp case WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING: WINDOWPOS* pos = (WINDOWPOS*)lParam; pos->hwndInsertAfter = HWND_BOTTOM; pos->flags = SWP_SHOWWINDOW | SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOMOVE; return 0; ``` The second method being the same without the `hwndInsertAfter` assignment and adding the flag `SWP_NOZORDER` Both give the same behaviour as previously though :/

Comment: If by "same behaviour as previously" you mean disappears when you press Windows+D, that isn't a z-order issue. As I said, your window is being moved off-screen. You would need to check for a move to those off-screen coordinates and set the `SWP_NOMOVE` flag to prevent it.

Comment: @JonathanPotter I also set the flag `SWP_NOMOVE` to prevent any movement, I put it in other events too to prevent any movement at all but it still disappears and remains invisible after hitting `Windows + D`. I wrote a `timer` function that logs the window's position (via the `GetWindowRect` function) along with a timestamp to the debug output to see what happens when I hit `Windows + D` ; turns out the coords don't move an inch, the function `IsWindowVisible` also returns true no matter if the window is on screen or hidden after a `Windows + D`, I don't see any difference in any of the values

Comment: Ok so @JonathanPotter you were right, don't know what exactly I messed up but I went back to the original code from the doc, recreated a timer to debug log the window's position and it's indeed moved to -32 000, -32 000 when hitting Windows + D. So in the end I just handled the events `WM_SIZE` & `WM_SETFOCUS` as well as `WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING` and setting the flags `SWP_NOMOVE` and `SWP_NOSIZE` if the window pos x is -32000.
Thanks again ! Going to write the final answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @JonathanPotter pointed out, when hitting `Windows + D` or the Show Desktop button, the event [`WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-windowposchanging) gets fired, and the window gets moved to `-32 000, -32 000` *(its size also gets changed)*

**NOTE** : a window without the style `WS_MINIMIZEBOX` seems not receiving `WINDOWPOSCHANGING` event when hitting Windows + D. Thus, no -32 000 coordinates detection in that case... Also noticed the same issue when using the ex style `WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW` *(as this one gets rid of the minimize box, even if you set the style flag `WS_MINIMIZEBOX`)*.
Didn't find a solution for that case, so I'm sticking to an overlapped window.

To prevent this movement, just set the flags `SWP_NOMOVE` and `SWP_NOSIZE` on the [`WINDOWPOS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/ns-winuser-windowpos) structure passed in the `lParam`

So as a final result, to achieve the wanted behaviour *(i.e always behind every other window but always in front of the desktop)*, the only needed code to add to the [doc's sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/windows/win32/learnwin32/your-first-windows-program) is the following, placed in the window procedure `WindowProc`'s switch statement :

**EDIT** : the best place to force the Z order with `HWND_BOTTOM` thus ensuring the window is always on bottom is also in the `WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING` event. Indeed, calling `SetWindowPos` to force it in the `WM_SIZE` event when dragging the window over, as I was doing previously, causes some flickering on the window when resizing it, whereas no flickering occurs when setting directly the `hwndInsertAfter` property of the `WINDOWPOS` structure in `WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING`.

```cpp
case WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING:
{
    WINDOWPOS* pos = (WINDOWPOS*)lParam;
    // Show desktop (Windows + D) results in the window moved to -32000, -32000 and size changed
    if (pos->x == -32000) {
        // Set the flags to prevent this and "survive" to the desktop toggle
        pos->flags |= SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE;
    }
    // Also force the z order to ensure the window is always on bottom
    pos->hwndInsertAfter = HWND_BOTTOM;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and found a solution via using "autohotkey". autohotkey is a powerful free scripting language for automation in windows that you can download from [here](https://www.autohotkey.com/). Below scripts are an instance of making sticky notes always on top when you execute it inside a .ahk file (you can copy these codes to a simple notepad and then change .txt to .ahk if you already had installed autohotkey on your computer). by right clicking on .ahk file, you can also see option of Compiling .ahk into .exe which enables you to share it with your other friends too:

```
#SingleInstance Force
GroupAdd, ontop, Sticky Notes ; you can replace sticky note by any application, 
                              ; if you know the name of that application window
                              ; (and its ahk_class for more specific cases). 
                              ; for example you can replace "Sticky Notes"
                              ; with "Calculator" to make calculator stay always
                              ; on top.

Loop {
 WinWait, ahk_group ontop
 WinSet, AlwaysOnTop, On
 SoundBeep, 1500
 WinWaitClose
 SoundBeep, 1000
}
```

(main codes are credit of [mikeyww](https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?t=103576))